# Default values for distinguished_name

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

Creating certificate:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/cakey.pem -out careq.pem -config ./openssl.cnf
```

I have value that tells openssl not prompt for `req_distinguished_name`  fields:

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
```

If I use value "no" I get error:

```
problems making Certificate Request
1995860064:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:158:maxsize=2
```

I suppose I need to fill all default values in configuration file. But what is missing?

```
Fragment of openssl.cnf:


[ req ]
prompt = no
default_bits            = 2048
#default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name # where to get DN for reqs
attributes              = req_attributes         # req attributes
x509_extensions     = v3_ca  # The extentions to add to self signed certs
req_extensions      = v3_req # The extensions to add to req's

string_mask = nombstr


[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default             = US
countryName_min                 = 2
countryName_max                 = 2

stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default     = California

localityName                    = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default            = Hawthorne

0.organizationName              = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default      = PhilNet

organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = UN

commonName                      = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_default              = CN
commonName_max                  = 64

emailAddress_default            = aaa@bbb.cc
emailAddress                    = Email Address
emailAddress_max
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 .... ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:158:maxsize=2
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^
```

It is not about missing values but about an invalid value

When reading [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/req.html) you'll see that using `prompt=no` changes the interpretation of the values in the config:

> **prompt**
>   if set to the value no this disables prompting of certificate fields and just takes values from the config file directly. It also changes the expected format of the distinguished_name and attributes sections.

This means that it will not take your `countryName_default` field to fill in the value but it will actually take the `countryName` field directly. But this field has the value `Country Name (2 letter code)` which is clearly larger than the maxsize.

See also [OpenSSL Config error when generating self-signed certificate string too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081575/openssl-config-error-when-generating-self-signed-certificate-string-too-long).